# Rolle's theorem violation or not?

Tags: calculus

Here is a question that I am trying to solve. Unsure about the best way to go about it. Could use some help:

**Question**
Let $f(x) = 1 - x^{\frac{2}{3}}.$ Show that $f(-1) = f(1)$ but there is no number c in (-1, 1) such that $f'(c) = 0$. Why does this not contradict Rolle’s Theorem?

**Answer explanation**

So Rolle's thereom says that if f(x) is continuous and differentiable and f(a) = f(b), then there is a number c in between `a` and `c` where the slope of f(x) is = 0.

First off, $f(-1) = 1 - 1 = 0$ and $f(1) = 1 - 1 = 0$

**Side question**
Quick question, why is that when I plug in $(-1)^{2/3}$ into google it does not give me -1. Am I wrong in saying that $(-1)^{2/3} = 1$?

So since f(1) and f(-1) both = 0, then I'm going to try to see if maybe the slope at f'(0) is = 0.

So here are a couple of ways that I determined this. Are both valid?

**Method 1**

$$f'(x) = -\frac{2}{3} x^{-1/3}$$

And that is undefined at x = 0 right? So since f(x) is not differentiable at x = 0, then this function isn't differentiable, and so Rolle's theorum is not violated.

**Method 2**

$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f'(x)$ is negative

$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f'(x)$ is positive

Does this show that the differential at 0 does not exist?

Comment: Did you read it before posting it?

Answer (score 1):

None of the two methods really proves that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Method $1$ only shows that the formula for the derivative is not valid at $0$, and method $2$ only shows that $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Both methods are still useful, though. It is clear that if $f$ is not differentiable at some point in $[-1,1]$, this point must be $0$.

You should prove that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^{2/3}}h$$

does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the function is not differentiable at $0$, and that is why Rolle's theorem does not apply. Your method 1 is not quite sufficient to show it, though: It could conceivably be that the function is differentiable at $0$, even though the expression you get from differentiating is not defined there. (Example: $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Your method 2 is better, but it needs more work too: To make use of the different limits of the derivatives from each side, you need to use L'Hôpital's rule to show that the two one-sided derivatives equal those limits. And since they are different (they are in fact $\pm\infty$), the function is not differentiable there. (This requires continuity, but you don't need to prove continuity, for if the function weren't continuous, it *definitely* wouldn't be differentiable.)

Finally, the most basic method is to employ the definition of derivative directly:
$$ f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{2/3}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}x^{-1/3}$$ does not exist.